# Jquery ajax call returns error when the rest service is returning a string

Tags: java, jquery, ajax, rest

Trying to send a simple text from my rest service and read it using ajax call. Found many answers about jsonp and cross browser compatibility, tried crossdomain too.

Here is the rest service:
Trimmed everything down to send only a simple string.

```
@GET
@Path("/getcontents2")
@Produces({MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN})
public String getContents2(@QueryParam("name") String msg) {
  return "abc";
}
```

The ajax call:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: 'http://metrics/getcontents2?name=Work/loc.txt',
    crossDomain: true,
    async: false,
    dataType:'html',
    success: function (data) {
      console.log(data);
    },
    error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
      console.log(xhr.status);
      console.log(thrownError);
      console.log(xhr.responseText);
      console.log(xhr);
    },
  });
});
```

The browsers opens up the string as is. I guess something is really wrong in the jquery script.

Error on Firebug:

```
GET http://metrics/getcontents2?name=Work/loc.txt 200 OK 4ms    
0 
(an empty string) 
(an empty string) 
Object { readyState=0, status=0, statusText="error"}
```

Answer (score 3):

Fixed it!

It was because my server was not supporting cross-domain. Configured it will corsfilter and it worked like a charm!

Comment: Had almost same problem. My webpage was on localhost, but web service was on server.

Answer (score 0):

try setting your datatype to <strike>text</strike> jsonp

```
dataType: 'jsonp',
```

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

You will have to do one of two things to go with this to resolve the error further;

1. making changes on the server side to pass the data back as json and not as text
2. retun the string encoded in json `return "{"text":"abc"}"; //or something like this`

### Why?

jquery cross-domain requests are only allowed for dataTypes "script" and "jsonp".

I have updated your [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/AtpzE/1/) it still throws an error but that is related to a parse json error

Comment: Tried text datatype and having the same issues. I guess html/text are treated the same way.

Comment: how are you generating the response on server side to http://metrics/getcontents2?name=Work/loc.txt what http headers does this url return?

Comment: I have used `@Produces("text/html")` and `return response.status(200).entity("test").build();`. Is there anything specific I need to give?

Comment: and it is it returning abc as expected just that jQuery is saying there is an error